# How to add mutiple test case results using WSAPI in Rally?

Tags: web-services, rally, wsapi

I am able to add a single test case result using the `/testcaseresult/create` API and passing the JSON as:

```
 {
    "testcaseresult":
    {
        "Build":5,
        "Date":"2017-02-27T18:03:29.260Z",
        "Testcase":{"_ref":"https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/TestCase/12345678"},
        "Verdict":"Pass"
    }
 }
```

Is there a way to add multiple test case results?

Comment: You can add multiple test case results to the same testcase in one request.  There's also a batch endpoint which you can create multiple items in one request.  Which rest toolkit are you using to integrate with wsapi?

Comment: I am working with Swift and so not able to use any toolkits. I am looking at the documentation for the WSAPI and trying to figure out from there. Can you link me to the batch endpoint?

Comment: I am planning to add test case results to different test cases at once. One result per test case. Is that possible?

Comment: You'll want to use the batch endpoint.  There is unfortunately not a nice page in the wsapi docs for it yet, but it's widely used across the product so is safe to use.  I'll write an example request format as an answer to this question shortly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the wsapi batch endpoint to create multiple items at the same time:

post url: `https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/batch`

post body:

```
{
    "Batch": [
        {
            "Entry": {
                "Path": "/testcaseresult/create",
                "Method": "POST",
                "Body": {
                    "testcaseresult": {
                        "Build":5,
                        "Date":"2017-02-27T18:03:29.260Z",
                        "Testcase": "/TestCase/12345678",
                        "Verdict":"Pass"
                     }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Entry": {
                "Path": "/testcaseresult/create",
                "Method": "POST",
                "Body": {
                    "testcaseresult": {
                        "Build":5,
                        "Date":"2017-02-27T18:03:29.260Z",
                        "Testcase": "/TestCase/1234",
                        "Verdict":"Fail"
                     }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: killer!  glad you got it.

Comment: How to do the same using the Rally REST API @KyleMorse

Comment: @Saikat `restApi.getClient().doPost("/batch", body)` should allow you to do it.  You'll just have to build up a JSON object and then convert it to a string for the second parameter.